# Cannot embed image/gif to GitHub page

Tags: github, embed

I'm trying to embed a GIF in a GitHub Pages page and tried every single way I found online can work. Here's my link:

https://github.com/jellyfishrui/Interactive-Programming-in-Python-Rice-University/blob/master/Week3/Stopwatch-the-Game/Instructions

The last line of code is the embedding code:

```
![StopWatch](https://github.com/jellyfishrui/Interactive-Programming-in-Python-Rice-University/blob/master/Week3/Stopwatch-the-Game/StopWatch.gif)
```

I also tried to embed the PNG (also saved as other formats like JPEG) and changed the extension to upper/lower case. But none of them can help me load the image. I also tried it on different browsers but they just all turned the same.

I tried the absolute/relative path and neither worked.

Comment: Your question mentions GitHub Pages, but I don't see a GitHub Pages site for this repository. Are you sure that's what you want? Or are you just trying to render Markdown within GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

That file has no file extension but you're trying to use Markdown for the image. Try renaming it to `Instructions.md`.

Also, make sure the casing of the file matches the file you've uploaded. Guessing what case to use isn't likely to work.